# reciving information from strings

Tags: c

I taking cures in c programming and I need to write a code.

I'm trying to receive a string from the user (no more than 80 characters) and than use it as a command.

the command looks like that - `<command name> <username> <number> <number>`.

I need to copy the username for a matrix name and to copy the number for the rows and colums and I don't really know how to do it.

hope anyone could help me.

Comment: It's not clear what help you need.

Comment: Use `scanf`, or `fgets` + `sscanf`.

Comment: hey thank u for the answer. after using the fgets, how can I find the second word in the string and copy her ? in need to create a matrix with this name.

Comment: Can the command have spaces in it? (e.g. `move window up`)? Or will the command be a single word?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

If there are spaces between the string of commands like

`command_name username number number,`

After using the `fgets()`, you can tokenize the string by space using [strtok()](http://devdocs.io/c/string/byte/strtok)

So, it returns an array with those tokens.

```
arr[4] = [(cmd name), (username), (number), (number)];
```

Then If you want to find the second word - username - in the string,

you just put it out in the array and use it.

```
char* user_name = arr[1];
```

I hope my answer is useful.

Here is an example code.

If you want to use `strtok()`

```
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

    int main(void)
    {
        char cmd[] = "Add kate 12 20";
        printf("input command : %s\n", cmd);
        char *token = strtok(cmd, " ");
        while(token) {
            puts(token);
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

or If you want to use `strtok_s()`,

```
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main(void)
    {
        char cmd[] = "Add kate 12 20";
        char *next_token;
        printf("input command : %s\n", cmd);
        char* token = strtok_s(cmd, " ", &next_token);
        while(token) {
            puts(token);
            token = strtok_s(NULL, " ", &next_token);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

the result is

```
input command : Add kate 12 20

Add

kate

12

20
```

Comment: it sounds right, but how do I use the strtok ? should it be like that ?
char * strtok(str2, arr)

str2 and arr are my strings, str2 it's the one i gets from the user and arr it's just arry for the strtok

Comment: i try to use strtok and it tells me to use strtok_s, when i try to use this it tells me there are not enough arguments. can u tell why?

Comment: If you are using visual studio, a compiler may recommend you that use strtok_s because of security issues. I will edit the example code.

Comment: If you want to know about 'strtok_s()' parameters, http://devdocs.io/c/string/byte/strtok, check this link.

Comment: i tried to copy the example code and it's don't work. it say that token in undefined, and i don't know how to defined it.

Comment: sorry, my mistake. try again.

Comment: sorry but still, no. i can run it now, but it's give an error - stop working.

Comment: well, it's not in English because my pc is in a different language. is there error code I can copy from somewhere?

Comment: We have google translator! just copy it in your language.

Comment: Unhandled exception at 0x0F590C79 (ucrtbased.dll) in Project9.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x002F7B5C.

maybe this will help? the main error is project1 has stop working.

Comment: I modified my strtok_s example code. try it again. I deleted 'strmax'.

Comment: it's work now! can u tell us what is the different between the first strtok_s to the second? why in the first one u use a string - cmd and in the second one u use null?
also, colud u tell us how to save all the tokens (words) in a new arry? thank u so much!

Comment: Those questions are too big to answer comments. So could you please create new Question post? then I will answer for you.

Comment: thank u a lot for the help, we manage to do it alone. your answer was really useful